# Make .NET Core DI auto resolve class by generic interface / abstract class implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control

Is there a way in .NET Core to register a generic interface, and make it resolve a class that matches a certain implementation.

For example, I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMapper<TFrom, TTo>
{
}
```

I also have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Mapper<TFrom, TTo> : IMapper<TFrom, TTo>
{
    protected Mapper()
    {
        // some generic stuff
    }

    public abstract TTo Map(TFrom);
}
```

I can then create an implementation like so:

```
public class UserMapper : Mapper<Domain.User, Entity.User>
{
    public override Entity.User Map(Domain.User from)
    {
        // do mapping
    }
}
```

Is there a way, using the default .NET Core DI to register `IMapper<,>`, and let it auto resolve the class?

So if I for example would do this somewhere in code:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IMapper<Domain.User, Entity.User> mapper) {}
}
```

That it somehow knows that it should resolve the class `UserMapper<Domain.User, Entity.User>`?

The reason is that it's a little verbose to manually register each and every mapper, specific to an implementation. So I'm hoping `Microsoft.DependencyInjection` is smart enough to automatically resolve its implementation somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way with your current design is to use Reflection:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(UserMapper).Assembly;

foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract))
{
    foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapper<,>))
        {
            // NOTE: Due to a limitation of Microsoft.DependencyInjection we cannot 
            // register an open generic interface type without also having an open generic 
            // implementation type. So, we convert to a closed generic interface 
            // type to register.
            var interfaceType = typeof(IMapper<,>).MakeGenericType(i.GetGenericArguments());
            services.AddTransient(interfaceType, type);
        }
    }
}
```

> NOTE: You could make it simpler by creating an extension method on `IServiceCollection` with the various overloads for `AddTransient`, `AddSingleton`, etc.

If you change the design use a non-abstract generic as your implementation type:

```
public class Mapper<TFrom, TTo> : IMapper<TFrom, TTo>
{
    //...
}
```

Then you can simply register like this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IMapper<,>), typeof(Mapper<,>));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more generic solutions (default scoped lifetime)

Create this extension method first

```
  public static void RegisterAllTypes(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly, Type baseType,
            ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
        {
            foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract))
            {
                foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseType))
                {

                    var interfaceType = baseType.MakeGenericType(i.GetGenericArguments());
                    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(interfaceType, type, lifetime));
                }
            }
        }
```

Then add this to startup.cs

```
 services.RegisterAllTypes(typeof(AClass).Assembly, typeof(IMapper<>));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have ready to use helpers:

**by Generic interfaces**

```
services.AddAllGenericTypes(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), new[] {typeof(MyDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly});
```

**By Interface**

```
services.AddAllTypes<IGenerator>(new[] { typeof(FileHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly },
```

With extension from:
https://gist.github.com/GetoXs/5caf0d8cfe6faa8a855c3ccef7c5a541