# .NET Core Register Raw Generic with Different Number of Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, solid-principles

I'm working on a .NET Core Project.  I need to automatically registers a default for some raw generics.  When there parameter count is the same everything works fine.

```
public void RegisterServiceDefaults(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton(typeof(IAdaptable<,>), typeof(DynamicAdapter<,>));
}
```

My `IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO>` works to allow dynamic adaptation between entities, but in my concrete services by default we expect an interface so we can control how each property is adapted to, my `IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO>` is really just a wrapper for convenience on this interface

```
IAdaptable<TEntity, TIDTO, TDTO>  
    where TDTO: TIDTO
{
}

IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO> : IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO, TDTO>
{
}
```

How can I generically register my adaptables so that if someone requests an `IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO, TDTO>` it will by default return the `IAdaptable<TEntity, TDTO>`?

**EDIT Provided for understanding the problem TL;DR**

This is being used for a rest framework which provides two ways of registration, the end user can create an `IAdaptable<TEntity, TIDTO, TDTO>`  a sample adapter might looks like so:

```
public UserAdapter : IAdaptable<User, IUserDTO, UserDTO>, IUserDTO
{
     User _user;

     public UserAdapter(User user)
     {
         this._user = user;
     }


     public int Id
     {
         get => this._user.Id;
         set { /*Do nothing you cannot override the server Id*/}
     }

     //... The rest of the User Properties
}
```

When a the end user creates a service they can use an `IAdaptable<TEntity, TIDTO, TDTO>` or if they do not want to create a concrete one they can pass some options to the dynamic one which is only aware of the `TEntity`, and `TDTO` property, no reason to create an `TIDTO` when it's only used for adapting.

Now when the end user creates a service they can rely on either interface, the GenericBase service by default requests an IAdaptable like so:

```
public class RestService<TEntity, TIDTO, TDTO>
    where TDTO: TIDTO
{
    public RestService(DbContext context, IAdaptable<TEntity, TIDTO, TDTO> adapter, IValidator<TEntity> validator)
    {
    }
}
```

and for a simplified version:

```
  public class RestService<TEntity, TDTO> : RestService<TEntity, TDTO, TDTO>
  {
     //Implementation...
  }
```

Now generally speaking, if the end user wants a dynamic adapter they should be using the simplified `RestService`, but depending on their architecture they maybe implement interfaces on the DTOs or maybe they just used the more explicit base and decide to use the `RestService<TEntity, TIDTO, TDTO>`,  In which case will leave them with a nasty runtime error.  So to avoid having my support team handle the end user error, I would like to avoid the situation and have the `IAdaptable<TEntity,TIDTO, TDTO>` work with my dynamic adapter which is a `IAdaptable<TEntity,TDTO>`.

Comment: This has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) written all over it.

Comment: @NightOwl888 how so? This is a bare bones MCVE, with an issue clearly laid out. I don’t understand how you can label this an XY question without knowing the requirements of my task, if you have a specific question I would gladly answer it

Comment: It might help (please read the link) if you explain the original problem that you are attempting to solve by using this design. I agree you have explained well what you *think* you want, but I have doubts this is *actually* what would be best to accomplish it.

Comment: I’ve provided a simple explanation without cluttering the question the interface is used so the user can provide properties in the adapter with custom mapping logic.  They should not have to manually register dynamic adapter nor should they have to rely on an implementation detail to get a default.  There constructor should be able to provide either interface and receive an dynamic adapter.  If you have an alternate solution I would love to hear it

Comment: @NightOwl888 okay I’ll provide an edit in a minute

Comment: All I am saying is there is something smelly about this design that makes me think that it is more than a DI registration issue. Could you provide an example of the `DynamicAdapter`?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Dynamic adapter is the one that works fine it's the concrete adapters that I'm attempting to support with a fallback to use the dynamic adapter,  I've provided a somewhat lengthy explaination but most of this is to support functionality requirements for the EndUser

Comment: @johnny5: What you want to do isn't possible with the .NET Core container. Although there is nothing inherently wrong with these kinds of complex generic mappings, your current question doesn’t allow us to give you feedback on whether there might be a better design. As I see it, you’ve got 2 options here. 1. either you more clearly describe the problem, and we can give you feedback on your design, or 2. you change to a different DI Container that actually supports these kinds of complex generic mappings (like Simple Injector and possibly Autofac).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make .NET Core DI auto resolve class by generic interface / abstract class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48852679)

Comment: @Steven thanks, I’ve provided the full scenario in the edit.  I’m trying to avoid tying the enduser into a specific DI container, I guess I’ll have to manually all of the potential adapter on the service factory

Comment: Actually, there is a 3rd option - scan using Reflection to register the type mappings. See the above duplicate for an example.

Comment: @NightOwl888 this is not a duplicate, I have no problem registering with the same amount of parameters.  But I do have to thank you, I think I came across your answer to create the defaults originally.  As Steven points out this is a limitation of the .net core default container

Comment: @NightOwl888 yeah I think I’ll have to go the reflection round and to my rest factory. If you want to provide that as an answer I’ll accept

Comment: Okay, I'll add it. Something still doesn't seem right with the design being that we are talking about *users*, but as long as you have taken into account that to add more types to the container the app must be restarted, I suppose there is no issue.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for your help, the users in the adapter was just a quick example.   I’ll add the types to the container during registration so I won’t have to restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own scanning implementation using Reflection to register multiple types with a single line.

### ServiceCollectionExtensions

Here we implement a simple `Scan` extension method that allows you to pick an an interface (whether generic or non-generic) and all implementations of that interface will be registered for all of the provided assemblies.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection Scan(
        this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        Assembly assembly,
        Type serviceType,
        ServiceLifetime lifetime)
    {
        return Scan(serviceCollection, new Assembly[] { assembly }, serviceType, lifetime);
    }

    public static IServiceCollection Scan(
        this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, 
        IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies, 
        Type interfaceType,
        ServiceLifetime lifetime)
    {
        foreach (var type in assemblies.SelectMany(x => 
            x.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract)))
        {
            foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                // Check for generic
                if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType)
                {
                    var genericInterfaceType = interfaceType.MakeGenericType(i.GetGenericArguments());
                    serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(genericInterfaceType, type, lifetime));
                }
                // Check for non-generic
                else if (!i.IsGenericType && i == interfaceType)
                {
                    serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(interfaceType, type, lifetime));
                }
            }
        }

        return serviceCollection;
    }

    // TODO: Add overloads ScanTransient, ScanSingleton, etc that call the 
    // above with the corresponding lifetime argument
}
```

### Usage

To register all of the types that close the generic `IAdaptable<,,>` type and register them as singleton, you would then simply need to use:

```
services.Scan(
    assembly: typeof(User).Assembly,
    interfaceType: typeof(IAdaptable<,,>), 
    lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```